# Angular 12 CSS not right

Tags: css, angular

I have the following css in my angular Component

```css
.folders {
  border-left: 5px solid #b8744f;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #fff;

  /*START*/
  background: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    center top,
    center bottom,
    from(#327aa4),
    color-stop(45%, #2e4b5a),
    to(#5cb0dc)
  );
  /*END*/

  background: -moz-linear-gradient(
    top,
    rgba(50, 123, 165, 0.75),
    rgba(46, 75, 90, 0.75) 50%,
    rgba(92, 176, 220, 0.75)
  );
  border: solid 1px #102a3e;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

The part marked between the comments START and END are not right as per the IDE. It keeps complaining like the following:

Mismatched parameters ([linear | radial] ,  , [ ,]?  [, ]? [, [color-stop() | to() | from()]]*)

-webkit-gradient is not working in angular 12
It keeps pointing to a parameter

[image: This image shows the error in Webstrom]

Comment: Are you targeting browsers where the browser-specific properties are necessary?

Comment: it is working fine. Check https://angular-ivy-gwkag6.stackblitz.io

Comment: It does not work in my browser since I updated to angular 12

Comment: Btw. CSS vendor prefixes are not required. To your problem: Use [linear-gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/linear-gradient()). I'm sure this will fix your issue.

Comment: The problem was with Chromium. Firefox was working

Answer (score 1):

Use [linear-gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/linear-gradient()):

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(
    #327aa4,
    #2e4b5a 45%,
    #5cb0dc
  );
}
```

CSS vendor / browser prefixes like `-webkit` or `-moz` are not necessary and makes the code messier and you repeat yourself (DRY). I recommend to use Angular with [SCSS](https://sass-lang.com/). Angular supports it out of the box.

If you want to rotate the gradient (e.g. horizontal) you can add the value `90deg`. See the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient) and web.

Comment: And works with all other (modern) browsers. Without browser prefix, etc.